# dirPaginate not working with ng-repeat-start(for expandable table)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

I am using a expendable table for that the code is below

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>S. No.</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Reporting to</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="position in listPositiondtls | itemsPerPage:10" current-page="currentPage">
            <td>
                <button ng-click="expanded = !expanded">
                    <span ng-bind="expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td >{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{position.positionName}}</td>
            <td>{{position.reportingToName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="expanded">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                    <span>Department Code: {{position.depCode}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                    <span>Department Name: {{position.depName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                    <span>Position Name: {{position.positionName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                    <span>Is He HOD: 
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="position.isHeadofdepartment">
                            <span class="text"></span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I am using ng-repeat-start directive for expandable table.
but pagination showing this alert:

```
Pagination directive: the pagination controls cannot be used without the corresponding pagination directive, which was not found at link time.
```

and an error:

```
pagination directive: the itemsPerPage id argument (id: __default) does not match a registered pagination-id.
```

Help me I need pagination in expandable table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 errors, i think.

- dirPaginate require use `dir-paginate` instead of `ng-repeat`.
- You need use pagination control `directive`.

To solve you problem do next:

- Change  `ng-repeat` on `dir-paginate` in `ng-repeat="position in listPositiondtls | itemsPerPage:10"`
- Add in html `<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>`

### Modified html

```
<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls> 
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>S. No.</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Reporting to</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="position in listPositiondtls | itemsPerPage:10" current-page="currentPage">
        <td>
            <button ng-click="expanded = !expanded">
                <span ng-bind="expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td >{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{position.positionName}}</td>
        <td>{{position.reportingToName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="expanded">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                <span>Department Code: {{position.depCode}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                <span>Department Name: {{position.depName}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                <span>Position Name: {{position.positionName}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 margin_all">
                <span>Is He HOD: 
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="position.isHeadofdepartment">
                        <span class="text"></span>
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I already tried it. in that case my expandable table is loosing its functionality
I need to keep my expandable table alive.

Comment: what I observed is that we can not replace dir-paginate with ng-repeat-start. it i can  only be replaced with  ng-repeat directive.
ng-repeat-start do not support dirPaginate...:(

Comment: `dir-paginate` does the same thing as `ng-repeat`. `dir-paginate-start` does the same thing as `ng-repeat-start` Provide working `jsfiddle `why your expandable table is loosing its functionality.

Comment: thanks for help. it's working fine now.
I was using 'ng-repeat-end' instead of 'dir-paginate-end'.

Comment: I have new issue. what should I do to not repeat the record in table body.
I have only one record to show in expandable table. for that I cant use ng-repeat-start. help me

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle. Then i can help you.